# Enviar dato por metodo POST javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, post, quasar

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto con vue js en quasar y quisiera saber como mandar un parametro mediante un metodo post para consumir una api, el codigo que realicé fue el siguiente:

```
export const EXPEDIENTE_API = ({RUT_ALUMNO}) =>{
    const url = `${expediente}/${RUT_ALUMNO}`
    return axios.post(url,{
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `token ${access_token}`   
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        return response
    }).catch((error) =>{
        return error
    })
}
```

Este código no me está funcionando, no sé que estaría mal, desde aquí hago el llamado a esta funcionalidad pero tampoco sé mucho como completar el código, si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería:

```
expediente() {
            let obj={
                RUT_ALUMNO: this.datosAlumno.rut
            }
            this.$store.dispatch("detalleExcepcion/EXPEDIENTE_ACTION", obj).then((res) =>{
                if(this.exceptionControl(res)){
                   
                }
                this.$q.loading.hide()
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                this.$q.loading.hide()
            })
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola en la documentación de [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) ellos dicen que debes mandar el post de la siguiente manera: `axios.post(URL, json, {headers})`

```js
axios.post('TU_URL', {
    ....tusdatos
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```